# How to bind MouseDoubleClick event in mvvm of ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, mvvm

I have a ListView with multi Columns.

I want to run a command when double click on a row. I use `EventTrigger` for this. But when i double click on every where of **ListView** run command. But I want to run this command when double click on `ListViewItem`.

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
  <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
    <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding ShowLetterCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=DashboardListView}" />
  </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should call `CallMethodAction` from **System.Windows.Interactions** library  and point at your method name at `MethdoName` like that:

I've made an example and it perfectly works:).
You need two libraries to handle `MouseDoubleClick` event:

- **System.Windows.Interactivity**(Address at my computer is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Expression\Blend\.NETFramework\v4.5\Libraries\`)
- **Microsoft.Expression.Interactions**(Address at my computer is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Expression\Blend\.NETFramework\v4.5\Libraries\`)

XAML:

```
<UserControl
 ...the code omitted for the brevity...
  xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
  xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
...the code omitted for the brevity...
>
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>             
   <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
                <ei:CallMethodAction MethodName="DoubleClickMethod" TargetObject="{Binding}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding IdPerson}" Margin="0,0,5,0"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>                
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

ViewModel:

```
public void DoubleClickMethod()
{
   MessageBox.Show("It is a Double Click");
   /*        if(parameter!=null)
       YourClass aClass=(YourClass)parameter; 
   */
}

private ObservableCollection<Person> persons;
public ObservableCollection<Person> Persons
{
   get { return persons; }
   set
   {
      persons = value;
      OnPropertyChanged("Persons");
   }
}

public MainWindowViewModel()
{
   LoadPersons();
}

private void LoadPersons()
{
   persons = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
   for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
   {
      Persons.Add(new Person() { IdPerson = i, Name = "Charlie " + i.ToString()});
   }
```

}

Model:

```
public class Person
{
    public int IdPerson { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

[The link to download a test project](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=D6BDF30773C16E01!2052&authkey=!AGjXucDT6kcJuFo&ithint=file%2Crar).

Comment: I have a command and CommandParameter, and want to set this for listviewitem . How to set this for `CallMethodAction `

Comment: Thanks, it is for ListView, and run command when doubleClick on it. but i want to run function when doubleclivk on listviewItem

Comment: Thanks, It is run function only when click in ListViewItem or run every where of ListView?

Comment: @ar.gorgin it works when you  **DoubleClick** at `ListViewItem`.

Comment: Thanks, I use this but it run when i double click every where of ListView :(

Comment: @ar.gorgin maybe you are confused that `SelectedItem` property highlights the whole length of row in `ListView` See my updated answer and link to download test project at the bottom of an answer.

Comment: Oh Yes , I set `Issynchronizedwithcurrentitem=true` . I want to get focus current item!!

Comment: @ar.gorgin it is really another question. Please avoid multiple questions at one theme. If my reply helps to you, you can mark my post as an answer and it helps and simplify future searching for other people.

Comment: i cannot find the libraries, even `Expression` folder not found. Is installing Blend necessary?

Comment: @LeiYang  yeah, try to install

Answer (score 0):

you can use Inputbindings to achieve this.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding SampleListData,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTree,Mode=TwoWay}" Name="dgSample">
        <ListView.InputBindings>
            <MouseBinding MouseAction="LeftDoubleClick" Command="{Binding ListDataEdited}"/>
        </ListView.InputBindings>
</ListView>
```

bind selected row to 'SelectedItem' .

**View Model :**

```
 #region Commands
    public RelayCommand ListDataEdited
    {
        get
        {
            return new RelayCommand(listDataEdited);
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Methods
    private void listDataEdited()
    {
        if (SelectedTree != null)
        {
            //code here
        }
    }
    #endregion
```

Comment: Thanks, but it is don't run command when i doubleclick on listviewitem.

Comment: @ar.gorgin try the syntax in column template, not listview itself.